# React Native : Avoid infinite loop with useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to **dispatch an action** to fecth an API when the home screen appears but I have an **infinite loop**.

My project :

- React Native app
- Redux
- redux-axios-middleware
- React Navigation (I am using a Drawer)

**What I tried:**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchNewMails = () => 
    return dispatch(ACTIONS.mailActions.fetchMails());
  };
  fetchNewMails();
}, [dispatch]);

-------

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const fetchNewMails = useCallback(() => {
  return dispatch(ACTIONS.mailActions.fetchMails());
}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    fetchNewMails();
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [fetchNewMails, navigation]);
```

A simple console.log is not producing infinite loop but the dispatch action yes ..

Thanks in advance if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is specific to my project but here it is:

I displayed a LoadingScreen in the App.js depending of Redux variable value, it was causing re-rendering.

Solution : Keep the LoadingScreen independent and delete it from App.js.

Issue solved.